# Caddy: Redirect www subdomain to main domain AND remove the trailing slashes

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, caddy

I am trying to redirect all www subdomain urls to the main domain.

The basic configuration is this one and it works fine:

```
https://www.{$HOST} {
    redir https://{$HOST}{uri} permanent
}
```

This works just fine
Example:
`https://www.my_domain.ltd/path/to/url` redirects to `https://my_domain.ltd/path/to/url` with a 301 code.

With that, I also want to get rid of the trailing slashes if they exists

Example:
`https://www.my_domain.ltd/path/to/url/` have to get redirected to `https://my_domain.ltd/path/to/url` and not `https://my_domain.ltd/path/to/url/`

Is there a way to do that using caddy's configuration?

I try this, but I got a parsing error:

```
https://www.{$HOST} {
    rewrite {
        to {path} {path}/ /{path}
    }
    redirect https://{$HOST}{uri} permanent
}
```

The error:  `Error during parsing: Wrong argument count or unexpected line ending after 'rewrite'`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to decouple the two different redirects, and in my local setup, it seems to work. So, you have your `www` to `non-www` redirect:

```
https://www.{$HOST} {
    redirect https://{$HOST}{uri} permanent
}
```

Leave it as it is. Then in the block which is handling `non-www`, add a redirect in case the path ends with a `/`

```
https://{$HOST} {

        # ... your content

        # matches paths with trailing '/'
        @pathWithSlash path_regexp static (.+)/$
        
        # captures location matching with given matcher
        handle @pathWithSlash {
                # redirect to matching regexp group         
                redir @pathWithSlash {re.static.1}
        }
        
        # ... other content
```

The **handle** [[1]](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/handle) works similarly to 'location' in NGINX, capturing all locations matching with the named matcher [[2]](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers#path-regexp) `@pathWithSlash`. The regexp captures URLs with a trailing slash and outputs the match without the trailing slash.